# Finding complex-equivalent of a real function ($\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$?)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm a bit confused at the problem above -- how precisely are they translating $$\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$$ into $$\frac{1}{2i}\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z}?$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\dfrac{e^{iz}-1}{z}=\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\cos{z}-1+i \sin z \right)$. If we take this along the real line, then the real and imaginary parts are $\dfrac{1}{x}(\cos x-1)$ and $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. So if we can deduce the complex integrand along the real line, then its real part will be the desired integral of $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. (The factor of $\frac{1}{2i}$ is probably for later convenience.) So using the complex integrand lets us find the desired real integral.

Comment: Cool, the separation of the integrand into real and imaginary parts makes sense -- one thing though (and this might be pretty fundamental): why do we use the complex integrand to find the desired real integral, not the real integrand?

Comment: @RyanYu: One of the key steps of the contour integration for this problrm is showing that the second integral in your brackets vanishes as $R\to \infty$. That can be done for $e^{i z}$ but not for $\sin z.$ To see the difference, plot their behaviors along the imaginary axis i.e. $z=iy$: $e^{-y}$ blows up in only one direction, but $\sin(iy)=-\sinh(y)$ blows up for both. So we've no hope of applying the same argument for sine as for $e^{i z}$.